# grequests парсит только первую страницу

Tags: python, grequests

1)Почему не парсятся все страницы, а только 1 страница во втором цикле?
2)Почему не находит все ключи?

```
import grequests
import json
import fake_useragent


urls=[]
try:
    for url in range(176288495,176288500):
        urls.append(f"https://steamcommunity.com/market/itemordershistogram?country=RU&language=russian&currency=5&item_nameid={url}&two_factor=0")
    responce=[grequests.get(u, headers={'user-agent' : fake_useragent.UserAgent().random}) for u in urls]
    maps=grequests.map(responce)
    print(maps)
    for count in maps: #
        js=json.loads(count.text)
        print(js)
        for key in js.keys():
            print(key)
            if key == 'buy_order_graph':
                order_price = float(js.get(key)[0][0])
            if key == 'sell_order_summary':
                quantily = int(str(re.findall("\d+", js.get(key))[0]).replace("{'", '').replace("'}", ''))
            if key == 'sell_order_graph':
                normal_price = float(js.get(key)[0][0])
        print(f'{order_price} -- {normal_price} -- {quantily} ')
except Exception:
    pass
finally:
    pass
```

Comment: 1. У меня ваш код парсит все страницы. 2. Вы про какие другие ключи говорите, кроме ключа 'buy_order_graph'?

Comment: sell_order_graph

Comment: и в правду парсит всё

Comment: @СергейШ, дополнил код полностью, можете проверить?

Comment: @СергейШ, уже не стоит, просто забыл добавить модуль

Comment: Ну собственно проблема из-за того, что все исключения тупо игнорируются, даже не печатается, что какая-то ошибка возникла. Вот так делать никогда не нужно, как минимум нужно добавить логирование ошибки: `except Exception: pass`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Забыл просто добавить модуль re
`import re`